# React-Redux, updating store on component inital render

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to change the Redux store value on component initial rendering.

Here is the code:

App.tsx

```
const { hour, location, people, date }: any = useSelector((state) => state);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

 useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(updateDate(new Date());
    dispatch(updateHour('17:00'));
    dispatch(updatePeopleCount(3));
    dispatch(updateLocation('California, USA'));
  }, []);
```

action.ts

```
export const updateDate = (date: Date) => {
  return { type: "Date", value: date };
};

export const updateHour = (hour: string) => {
  return {
    type: "Hour",
    value: hour,
  };
};

export const updatePeopleCount = (people: number) => {
  return {
    type: "People",
    value: people,
  };
};

export const updateLocation = (location: string) => {
  return {
    type: "Location",
    value: location,
  };
}
```

After useEffect hook is called, the data accessed from useSelector hook doesn't change.

Comment: Why would you get a value from redux store: `const { hour, location, people, date }: any = useSelector((state) => state);` and use that value to update redux store? I would also suggest you check your [linting messages](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/14920).

Comment: I didn't use that value, If you see from useSelector im getting parameter hour, but I'm updating store with variable hourParam. It's a diffrent variable.

Comment: In that case your code will bug out with `Uncaught ReferenceError: hourPraram is not defined` because `hourParam` is not defined anywhere.

Comment: `hourParam` is defined, but I didn't mention it, because it was not the root of the problem. I've changed the question already to make it clear.

Comment: What does the redux devtools say? Did you update the state after the action was dispatched? Did you accidentally mutate the state in the reducer so the selector is not run again?